# Equations involving $2 \times 2$ Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

There are two possible values of A in the solution of the matrix equation

$\left[\begin{matrix}2A+1&-5\\-4&A\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\cdot \left[\begin{matrix}A-5&B\\2A-2&C\end{matrix}\right]= \left[\begin{matrix}14&D\\E&F\end{matrix}\right]$ where $A,B,C,D,E,F \space all \space \in \mathbb{R}$. The absolute value of the difference of these two solutions is?

Options given :

1. $\dfrac{8}{3}$
2. $\dfrac{11}{3}$
3. $\dfrac{1}{3}$
4. $\dfrac{19}{3}$

I have first obtained the result of  $\left[\begin{matrix}2A+1&-5\\-4&A\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}$

$= \dfrac{1}{(A(2A+1)-20)} \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}A&5\\4&2A+1\end{matrix}\right]$

where $\left[\begin{matrix}A&5\\4&2A+1\end{matrix}\right] =$ adjoint($\left[\begin{matrix}2A+1&-5\\-4&A\end{matrix}\right]$)

Then the next step is to find

$\dfrac{1}{(A(2A+1)-20)} \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}A&5\\4&2A+1\end{matrix}\right] \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}A-5&B\\2A-2&C\end{matrix}\right]= \left[\begin{matrix}14&D\\E&F\end{matrix}\right]$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{(A(2A+1)-20)} \cdot \left[\begin{matrix}A(A-5)+10(A-1)&AB+5C\\4(A-5)+2(A-1)(2A+1)&4B+C(2A+1)\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}14&D\\E&F\end{matrix}\right]$

$\therefore \dfrac{A^2-5A+10A-10}{2A^2+A-20}=14$[From the above written equation]

$\implies 27A^2+23A-270=0$

whose curve is like this :

[image]

and the roots are :

$-10$, $-\dfrac{23}{27}$

The difference between the two is $-\dfrac{247}{27}$

Hence none of the options are matching. Where am I wrong and if Yes, please correct me and give the correct answer please. I request anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First keep in mind that if $x_{1,2}$ are the roots of a quadratic $ax^2+bx +c=0,\,a\neq 0$ then

$$|x_1-x_2|={\sqrt{\Delta}\over a}$$

Second you do not need to invert the first matrix just multiply both sides with it so the matrix equation is equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix} A-5 & B\\2A-2 & C\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2A+1 & -5\\-4 & A\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}14 & D\\E & F\end{bmatrix}$$

This is equivalent to

$$\begin{bmatrix} A-5 & B\\2A-2 & C\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}28A+14-5E & (2A+2)D-5F\\-56+AE & -4D+AF\end{bmatrix}$$

We just identify the first column

$$\begin{cases} 5E=27A+19\\5EA=10A+270\end{cases}$$

Substituting $5E$ one gets

$$3A^2+A-30=0$$

This means $\Delta=361=19^2$ and

$$|x_1-x_2|={19\over 3}$$

Your mistake is in the last transformation

$$A^2-5A+10A=28A^2+14A-280\iff 27A^2+9A-270\iff 3A^2+A-30=0$$

Comment: I understand the simplicity by which you solve this question which is appreciable.

Comment: Laziness is a key to success, the less you do the better.